# @polkadot/typegen is generating erroneous code

Tags: polkadot-js

We are using @polkadot/typegen for TypeScript user generated code for Chain modules [script](https://github.com/AstarNetwork/astar.js/blob/main/packages/types/scripts/generate.ts). We are getting errors as code generated includes many new types taken from chain but they are not imported.

[image]

Comment: Corresponding issue https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/5503 opened in polkadot-js/api